# What does mean host in lsscsi command?

Tags: disk, scsi

A notebook has only one SSD (without CDROM drive)

if I take a look at /proc/scsi/scsi it outpus:

```
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: KINGSTON SUV500M Rev: 56RI
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

If I run lssci it results in:

```
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      KINGSTON SUV500M 56RI  /dev/sda
```

However `lsscsi -H` it outputs:

```
[0]    ahci          
[1]    ahci          
[2]    ahci
```

why are 3 entries of ahci?

Answer (score 0):

"Host" is the interface to which a SCSI device is attached, including interfaces like USB, which are not physical.

`lsscsi` reports the low level SCSI driver's name, i.e. the name of that interface. You find it under `/sys/class/scsi_host/*/proc_name` and `/proc/scsi`. I don't know if it has a practical use for system administrators.

On my server (ARM-based credit-card-sized thing), I have a USB disk with host "usb-storage". The usb-storage driver is compiled into my kernel, and I don't seem to have a usb-storage kernel module.

More reading:

- [Low-level SCSI driver interface documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scsi/scsi_mid_low_api.html)
- [lsscsi documentation](http://sg.danny.cz/scsi/lsscsi.html)
- a similar [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878843/determine-linux-driver-that-owns-a-disk)

Comment: Nice information, I've reformulated my main question, but still I don't know why are 3 entries of ahci driver...

Comment: Because you have three SCSI interfaces. Only one of them has a disk attached. Try `lspci` to see if there are more physical interfaces in your laptop. Or perhaps the driver needs to create hosts 0 and 1 for some reason, or some other kernel component, or perhaps udev. The kernel startup messages may shed some light on this.

Comment: `dmesg` on an old Thinkpad tells me: `ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x13 impl SATA mode`. I interpret this as one interface with six ports, and wouldn't you know, `lsscsi -H` reports six ahci interfaces. I learned something :)